# Pass number of the button in the name of the variable

Tags: c#

I have this lines of code:

```
button0.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
button1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
button2.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
...
```

How can I make correct this:

```
(button + "numberOfButton").BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: Store buttons in an array and do like that: `button[numberOfButton]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you find yourself with variables like this:

```
button0
button1
button2
etc...
```

What you *should* have is an array.  If the controls themselves are already static on the form, then you can simply build the array when loading the form.  Something like this:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private IEnumerable<Button> myButtons;

    public MyForm()
    {
        myButtons = new List<Button>
        {
            button0, button1, button2 // etc...
        };
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Then when you need to loop over the buttons, you simply loop over the collection:

```
foreach (var button in myButtons)
    button.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

If you need to reference the collection elements by index, use an `IList<>` instead of an `IEnumerable<>`.  If you need to do more complex things, use [any number of collection types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by name with method [Control.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(VS.80).aspx):

```
var button = this.Control.Find("button0", true).FirstOrDefault();
```

But better to store buttons in array and get them by index:

```
var buttons = new Control[10];
buttons[0] = button0;
...
```

Comment: This seems to be a desktop app question, not a web app